# How to create javascript function in laravel foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.8

I need some help about this code

I have some code in blade view

```
@foreach($cart as $ct)
<button type="button" id="edit{{$ct->id}}" class="btn-btn-delete">
        <i class="mr-1 fas fa-edit"></i>Edit
</button>
        //when I {{$ct->id}} at this point, it return id of current product         
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm{{$ct->id}}">
        //however, when I {{$ct->id}} at this point, it return id of the last product                      
    <form action="{{route('cart.update',$ct->id)}}" class="form-container" method="post">
            @csrf
            @method('patch')
           <h1>Edit information</h1>

           <input type="text" name="name" value="{{$ct->name}}">
          <button type="submit" class="btn">change</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn cancel" id="close{{$ct->id}}">Close</button>
     </form>
</div>

 <script>
     var ID = {{$ct->id}};
     var code = 'edit'+ID;
     var end = 'close'+ID;
     var form = 'myForm'+ID;
     document.getElementById(code).addEventListener("click",function(){
               document.getElementById(form).style.display = "block";
              });
     document.getElementById(end).addEventListener("click",function(){
               document.getElementById(form).style.display = "none";
              });
 </script>
@endforeach
```

when I run my code and click on `Edit` button the expected value in `input` field of each row must be different. However, it all gets the value of the last column in the database.

How I can fix it?

Comment: Not the only issue but you can't repeat element ID's in a page. They are unique by definition. Learning how to use more modern `addEventListener` instead of inline `onclick` would also be helpful

Comment: @charlietfl I just try to update my code as you said, however, it still does not work

Comment: You shouldn't merge JS and PHP together, have separate files.

Comment: @ThanhTrung If I don't do that how I can get the element id for each my data row?

Comment: Current approach still requires the js  being mixed  in the php but you can fix the current code by quoting the `ID` variable string. `var ID = "{{$ct->id}}";` so it is a valid string value in javascript

Comment: Moving it all to a js file and using classes to query the elements and attributes within the event handler is more modern approach and a *"separation of concerns"*

Comment: It's called passing information through data attributes. Do you use jQuery? If yes I'll make an example using jQuery

Comment: Skip that last comment....the loop will keep overwriting each of the `var` since they are in global namespace. Once page has loaded .... `form ` and `end` will always be the last ones when event occurs

Comment: then, how I can fix it?

Comment: Not pretty but wrapping eaach of those code blocks in an *IIFE (Immediately Invoking function Expression)* would work. My answer shows a more practical solution that separates js from php completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is approach using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and classes to target elements as well as data attributes (like `data-target="myForm1"`) for element specific data to use inside an event handler.

It is currently working for the "Edit" and "Cancel" buttons which have the same class `popup-toggle` along with their other existing classes.

You can use this approach as a template for your other elements/actions

```js
// in DOMContentLoaded event handler or after elements exist

const popToggleButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.popup-toggle');

[].slice.call(popToggleButtons).forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', handleToggleBtnClick)
});


function handleToggleBtnClick(event) {
  const btnData = this.dataset,
    popup = document.getElementById(btnData.target),
    classMethod = btnData.action === 'show' ? 'add' : 'remove';
  // add or remove active class depending on which button was clicked
  popup.classList[classMethod]('active');

}
```

```css
.form-popup {
  display: none
}

.form-popup.active {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" data-target="myForm1" data-action="show" class="popup-toggle btn-btn-delete">
        <i class="mr-1 fas fa-edit"></i>Edit #1
</button>
  <div class="form-popup" id="myForm1">
    <form action="..." class="form-container" method="post">
      <h1>Edit information #1</h1>
      <input type="text" name="name" value="name 1">
      <button type="submit" class="btn">change</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn cancel popup-toggle" data-target="myForm1" data-action="hide">Close</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" data-target="myForm2" data-action="show" class="popup-toggle">
        <i class="mr-1 fas fa-edit"></i>Edit #2
</button>

  <div class="form-popup" id="myForm2">
    <form action="..." class="form-container" method="post">
      <h1>Edit information #2</h1>
      <input type="text" name="name" value="name 2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn">change</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn cancel popup-toggle" data-target="myForm2" data-action="hide">Close</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```